# Change default "find" behaviour of Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I have number of fields with field, let's say, `archived`. I want to skip all models with this field set to `true` in all search/update operation but do not want to specify it explicitly in each query, but able to override it when explicitly passed. Is it possible to do it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [Query Middlewares](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) available in Mongoose.

> In query middleware, mongoose doesn't necessarily have a reference to
>   the document being updated, so this refers to the query object rather
>   than the document being updated

```
schema.pre('find', function() {
  console.log(this instanceof mongoose.Query); // true
  this.where('archived', false);
});
```

Comment: I know about middlewares and have number in my app. It is unsuitable for this case because works only for extending schema and catching save/remove/init events (not `find`).

Comment: There is a specific query middleware which can be used to modify `find` queries. I'm attaching a link to the [specific section](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) in the documentation.